# How do I Improve and Scale my App Development Workflow?

Tags: python, git, iis, workflow, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Python web application built with Django. It is served on IIS on a Windows Server 2012. This server is a remote server to which I have access. My current development process looks like one of these two things (depending on the day):

- Directly edit the Python code on the remote server and hope changes don't break anything (and if they do, quickly try to fix them)
- Copy the entire web app to my local machine, make changes there and get it working, then copy the code snippets that I changed to the server version

These are obviously not ideal ways to develop and deploy an application. What specific steps can I take to make this better, more flexible, and more scalable? This is what I have come up with so far:

- I need to start using git, and I can install that on both the local and remote machines
- However, I cannot communicate with the remote server via SSH
- I also don't think I can communicate with the remote server with HTTPS, because the only viable git web server for IIS is Bonobo, and it does not appear to be active/fully supported. Other self-hosted options (i.e. gitea) appear to need open ports such as 80 and 443...which the IIS site needs.
- I could (unlikely, but potentially) use GitLab to hand code revision, but it would not be hosted on the same remote server (which is where deployment must take place)

What are the primary options to make this workflow more bearable and stable?

Comment: Why can you not use ssh?

Comment: not allowed by the admins

Comment: Not allowing SSH sounds like the admins don't know what it is? Maybe you can use something like rsync?

Comment: that still uses rsh or ssh though, right? agreed on them not necessarily understanding it